# How to use FragmentStatePagerSupport whitout having to use a list in it?

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm following the example [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) and I get it to work.
But problem is that I don't have a list to display so I wonder how do I modify the functions so that they don't need a list element in the xml to work?

I want my " R.layout.fragment_pager_list" to look like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:drawable/gallery_thumb">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"/>

    <!-- The frame layout is here since we will be showing either
    the empty view or the list view.  -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <!-- Here is the view to show if the list is emtpy -->
        <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="No items."/>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I.E not having to have the

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
```

In it. How can I modify

```
public static class ArrayListFragment extends ListFragment {
        int mNum;

        /**
         * Create a new instance of CountingFragment, providing "num"
         * as an argument.
         */
        static ArrayListFragment newInstance(int num) {
            ArrayListFragment f = new ArrayListFragment();

            // Supply num input as an argument.
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("num", num);
            f.setArguments(args);

            return f;
        }

        /**
         * When creating, retrieve this instance's number from its arguments.
         */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
        }

        /**
         * The Fragment's UI is just a simple text view showing its
         * instance number.
         */
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list, container, false);
            View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
            ((TextView)tv).setText("Fragment #" + mNum);
            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Cheeses.sCheeseStrings));
        }

        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            Log.i("FragmentList", "Item clicked: " + id);
        }
    }
}
```

In order to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want lists, do not use a `ListFragment` for the pages. Create your own `Fragment` with your own page UI. For example, [here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Fragments) that uses fragments, each hosting an `EditText` widget.